# arrange->send backward not sending graphics behind

Tags: flash, graphics, vector, cs4

I'm following instructions to make a simple background in Flash CS4 using vector graphics. I'm at the part where the book tells me to put the cloud graphics behind a hill I drew by clicking  modify->arrange->send backward, however, clicking that option does not seem to do anything.

Edit: the hill and clouds are on the same "foreground" layer, my bad!

SOLUTION: I got it to work by converting the hill into a graphic symbol.

The clouds circled are supposed to be behind the hill:
[image]

Comment: Voting to close because the question is unanswerable (you found a solution that isn't related to the body of the question).

Comment: Actually, I got it to work by converting the hill into a graphic symbol. The book I was reading didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually drag the layer that holds your clouds (next to the timeline) so that it's listed underneath the layer holding your hills.

[image]

Using **send backward** only applies to the children/graphics of the layer you're working on.

Just a note: looking at your layers and current graphics it seems that the blue elements are also on the layer "background". If this is the case, your clouds will disappear behind the blue also. You'll need to make an additional layer which holds just the blue (sky and water?) and place that below the clouds AND the hills.

Comment: sorry, the clouds and hill are on the same layer!

Answer (score 1):

this is confusing because Flash has so many places to put things, but your issue is that you have the clouds in a different layer (in the Timeline tab). Things that are in the SAME layer can be pushed around on the z axis. Separate layers need to be moved up and down in the timeline order, just drag it beneath wherever you want it, and it will move behind that layer.

Comment: my bad, the clouds and hill are on the same layer!